# BGTaskScheduler.shared.register Not Called

Tags: swift, xcode, background-fetch

I'm using background refresh to schedule local notifications and update my widget.
The problem is that the task registration method isn't called!

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        
    BGTaskScheduler.shared.register(forTaskWithIdentifier: "com.Mahmoud.AdaniLite.AppRefresh", using: nil) { task in
        print("Registered")
        self.handleAppRefresh(task: task as! BGAppRefreshTask)
    }
  return true
}
```

I also have a break point inside the *register* method with a print statement but non of both worked!

**I have done my research and so far i have tried the following already:**

1. I made sure 'Permitted background task scheduler identifiers' in the info.plist is filled with the correct task identifier. I have triple checked that this string gets used correctly in the code as well.
2. Enabled 'Background fetch' capability.
3. In the info.plist I added "App processes data in the background" to the "Required background modes"
4. I'm running the app on a real device running iOS 15

Any help or guidance is deeply appreciated!

Comment: Without seeing more of your code, there is no reason for us to believe you're doing something that makes sense. It's also unclear what you expect to happen.

Comment: I have the exact same problem in a SWIFTUI App. To clarify: what creates means: self.handleAppRefresh(task: task as! BGAppRefreshTask) ist not called.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?  I have this exact same issue.  The register function is called, but the completion handler (closure) never executes, so handleAppRefresh is never called.

Answer (score 0):

You’ve only registered your task handler so far. You also need to schedule your background task.

Please see this guide for more information: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/scenes/preparing_your_ui_to_run_in_the_background/using_background_tasks_to_update_your_app

It can be a bit unpredictable when your background task will be executed, and might not happen at all exactly when you expect it to.

This outlines how you can debug your task handlers to make sure they’re registered and have correct requests submitted:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/backgroundtasks/starting_and_terminating_tasks_during_development

Comment: I read it many times. I've schedules the background task but it didn't work. Why the 'register' block was not called in the first place! thanks for the help

Comment: Added some details about how to debug background tasks.

Comment: I downloaded Apple's code example from here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/backgroundtasks/refreshing_and_maintaining_your_app_using_background_tasks And I added break point inside BGTaskScheduler.shared.register but it wasn't called either!

Comment: @4mahmoud It's not going to be called when you are sitting there running the app from Xcode. _It's a background task._

Comment: Please read what @4mahmoud ist not that the background task is not called. The register process self.handleAppRefresh(task: task as! BGAppRefreshTask) ist not called

Comment: i actually am experiencing the same. .register() runs but never gets inside the closure to run handleAppRefresh(). I followed all the instructions in the doc. Running this in SwiftUI in the App's init() function.

Comment: Same for me.  The completion handler is never called.

Comment: When running your build in Xcode, try Debug pulldown menu > Simulate Background Fetch.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem as you, and I've been trying to solve it for several hours!

And I've found a solution!

Here are the steps:

In the AppDelegate:

```swift
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions _: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
    // …
    SchedulingService.shared.registerBackgroundTasks()
    return true
}
```

My service:

```swift
class SchedulingService {
    static let shared = SchedulingService()
        
    func registerBackgroundTasks() {
        let isRegistered = BGTaskScheduler.shared.register(forTaskWithIdentifier: "com.YOUR.refresh", using: nil) { task in
            print("Background task is executing: \(task.identifier)")
            self.handleAppRefresh(task: task as! BGAppRefreshTask)
        }
        print("Is the background task registered? \(isRegistered)")
    }
    
    func scheduleAppRefresh() {
        let request = BGAppRefreshTaskRequest(identifier: "com.YOUR.refresh")
        
        request.earliestBeginDate = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 60 * 2)
        
        do {
            try BGTaskScheduler.shared.submit(request)
        } catch {
            print("Could not schedule app refresh: \(error)")
        }
    }
    
    private func handleAppRefresh(task: BGAppRefreshTask) {
        // <!-- Your background logic here -->
        // <!-- LocalNotificationService.sharedInstance.initScheduleNotifications() -->

        task.setTaskCompleted(success: true)
        
        scheduleAppRefresh()
    }
}
```

Now, put a breakpoint in the closure at this line:
`self.handleAppRefresh(task: task as! BGAppRefreshTask)`

Relaunch your app with Xcode (no need to modify the Scheme), put your app in the background with a swipe up, and wait between 5 to 20 minutes, doing nothing else. Make sure your debugger is still attached to your app, and feel free to add print statements throughout to trace execution. Eventually, you should enter the closure and hit your breakpoint. After that, press "Continue" and wait another 2 to 3 minutes, and you should see the `self.handleAppRefresh(task: task as! BGAppRefreshTask)` function trigger again.

I hope this helps.

Please note that I'm using an iPhone 11 with a cable.
Xcode Version 15.2